# Генерация кода в разные файлы

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Компилятор GWT из байт-кода всех классов генерирует всё в один большой js-файл.
Мне нужно сгенерировать из java-кода javascript-код, который бы находился в разных файлах. Например, в зависимости от модуля. Как это сделать?

Comment: Думаю, что это невозможно. Там же нужно будет все зависимости проследить, а пока такой функциональности нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это возможно с помощью метода GWT.runAsync. GWT-компилятор каким-то волшебным образом разбивает код в местах вызова этого метода.

Подробное описание [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CodeSplitting)

Comment: А что происходит с зависимостями?

Comment: @wildFrog с зависимостями между GWT модулями? А что с ними может произойти? Или вы используете dependency injection на клиенте? В любом случае, если следовать рекомендациям разработчиков, которые приведены в описании, всё работает прекрасно :)